# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Label' of undefined in SAPUI5 Mobile App for cross platforms Android using PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, sapui5, phonegap

While developing application on  SAPUI5 Mobile App for cross platforms Android using PhoneGap I am facing issue like:

> faile:///android-asset/www/resources/sap-ui-core.js:Line 117: 
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Label' of undefined.

My Code is like:

```
var lab=new sap.m.Label({text: "From :",width:"100px"});
var dat1= new sap.m.DateTimeInput("dt1",{placeholder:"mm/dd/yyyy",value:before,valueFormat : "MM/dd/yyyy",displayFormat : "MM/dd/yyyy"});
var hb= new sap.m.HBox({items:[lab,dat1]});

var lab1=new sap.m.Label({text: "To :",width:"100px"});
var dat2= new sap.m.DateTimeInput("dt2",{placeholder:"mm/dd/yyyy",value:today,valueFormat : "MM/dd/yyyy",displayFormat : "MM/dd/yyyy"});
var hb2 = new sap.m.HBox({items:[lab1,dat2]});
```

The not loading sap.m.Label, sap.m.Button....so on .

Could please suggest me to avoid this issue.

I have added `sap-ui-core.js`  at `myproject/assets/resources/`

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I have no experience using PhoneGap with UI5 but from the UI5 perspective I can say that `sap-ui-core` does not contain the mobile controls. This means you have to add `sap.m` library to the resources.

Comment: Hello Tim Gerlach,

  Thank you so much for your response.I resolved the issue, I missed some SAPUI5 library elements.

Thanks,

Nag

Comment: @user3624736 It would be nice if you include your solution as an answer so that others can also benefit. Or simply delete your question.

Comment: Hello Tim,
 Thank you Tim.This issue was resolved. The reason for this issue is some library is missed in downloaded SAPUI5 library. For solution I have added all required libraries in resources folder.And I have included cordova.jar in build path of project in Eclipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments the `sap.m` libraries were missing as resources and in the bootstrap. Keep in mind that `sap-ui-core.js` is only the starting point 
of the UI5 Framework but not the whole framework. Including only this file to your project is **not** sufficient.

Make sure that you always include all necessary files (Runtime Version) to your ressources. You can get the latest from the official [OpenUI5](http://openui5.org/download.html) site. If you only need the `sap.m` controls you can use the stripped-down *UI5 Runtime Mobile* version.

A proper bootstrap could look like this:

```
<script
    id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="path/to/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m">
```